# connection Issue between FreeSwitch and softphone

Tags: centos7, freeswitch

I'm having a connection issue between my X-Lite softphone and FreeSwitch. I get an error from the softphone saying "Failed to establish call," however SIP registration succeeds.

Here are the setup details:
X-Lite softphone app is installed on my Windows 10 VM.
FreeSwitch is installed on my Centos7 VM.
Both VMs are on the same network.

I can turn off firewalld on Centos and calls do go through successfully, so it's definitely a firewall configuration issue.

Here's what I've tried:
1. I created a custom freeswitch service for firewalld for it to open up the 2 ports for the default external and internal profiles, but still getting the same error.
2. I've installed iptraf on Centos to monitor traffic. I've noticed the following message: "ICMP dest unrch (host comm denied) (576 bytes) from CENTOS_IP to WINDOWS10_IP on eth0".

Not really sure what else I can do to debug this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit my firewalld custom service file to allow udp traffic as well. It previously only allowed tcp traffic. So, my service file now looks like this:

FreeSwitch
  This is a service that handles a variety telephony functionality

Just replace EXTERNAL_PROFILE_PORT and INTERNAL_PROFILE_PORT with your true profile ports. The defaults are 5080 and 5060 respectively.

Side Note: You may also want to open up the port range for rtp traffic, otherwise you maybe be able to call out but won't hear any sound coming across. The default rtp port range for freeswitch is 16384-32768 and it uses udp protocol. So, you can open up a port range like this: sudo firewall-cmd --zone=home --add-port=16384-32789/udp. Just make sure to change the zone to the one you want to modify. In the command above is set to "home" zone. Test to make sure it works and then run the same command with the "permanent" argument to make the change permanent: sudo firewall-cmd --zone=home --permanent --add-port=16384-32789/udp.